# VSCode Problems Tab: How to subscribe to onclick event on one specific problem

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am developing a VSCode extension (a graphical modeler, not text based).  On validate some errors/problems can show up in the VSCode problems tab. (Diagnostics Collection).  How can I intercept a click event on a specific problem listed in the problems tab?  I need to highlight the related object in my custom modeler.  It seems there is only a standard built-in behavior in VSCode to scroll to a text-line. I can't find an API to subscribe to click events on problems in the VSCode problems tab.

Scenario:

- We have a graphical custom editor for BPM as VSCode extension running in a Webview (A non text-based editor: See screenshot)
- There is a validator and several problems can be show up in VS Code problems tab (As a diagnostic collection).
- When user clicks on specific problem (e.g. the 3rd message) How can we now the user clicked on the 3rd problem in the list of problems? We want to use that user-event to show some (problem text or solution) in the graphical modeler.  So we can't make use of the VSCode built-in features for text based languages.

[Screenshot VSCode Graphical Custom Editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i96MW.png)

Comment: `vscode.languages.registerCodeActionsProvider`

Comment: Hi RioV8.  this CodeActionProvider seems to be a solution for Text based editors.  I have a custom webview with a grahical modeler. So in my DiagnosticCollection I don't have a meaningfull source line/position.  I need to scroll to a (graphical) object in the webview.  Any idea?  Is there an API to intercept the mouse-click on lines in the VSCode problem tab?

Comment: method `resolveCodeAction` of the `CodeActionsProvider`