# How to listen to "problem selection changed" event?

Tags: vscode-extensions

I have a graphical custom editor and associated problem markers in the problem view. When a problem is selected, the correct editor is focused, but the affected element is not selected. To select the correct element, a custom handler would be required.

Is it somehow possible to subscribe to "problem selection changed" event? With this subscription, I could run the custom element selection.

I am aware of [VSCode Problems Tab: How to subscribe to onclick event on one specific problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72216574/vscode-problems-tab-how-to-subscribe-to-onclick-event-on-one-specific-problem). The solution seems not to work for graphical editors.

For clarification, see the following example, in which a problem selected in the view does not lead to an element selection in the graphical custom editor.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bzZJT.gif)

Comment: Try to run your extension in debug mode

Comment: I do, but debug what? I have no idea if there is a listener for my needs and if so, which one.